# Add docx file in resources and create executable jar

Tags: java, jar, uri

I want to add

- docx files in resources folder, use those files in code written in class located at another package of same application.
- And then I want to make an executable jar out of it which will be working on windows.

I read its not easy to make such jar :( and there is no fool prroof way...

I have tried searching for it on net and found I will have to create URL and then file and then use it...
however, when I use below code, I am not able to get URL itself...

```
URL urlOfDraftInSamePackage = CreateDraft.class.getResource("Draft_in_same_package.docx");
        System.out.println("urlOfDraftInSamePackage is "+urlOfDraftInSamePackage.toString());
```

//This prints : urlOfDraftInSamePackage is file:/D:/aditya_workspace/SampleDraftMaker/bin/draftProcessing/Draft_in_same_package.docx

```
URL urlOfDraftInResourceFolder = CreateDraft.class.getResource("resouces/Draft_Apartment.docx");
        System.out.println("urlOfDraftInResourceFolder is "+urlOfDraftInResourceFolder.toString());
        //this gives null pointer exception
        URI uri = null;
        try {
            uri = urlOfDraftInSamePackage.toURI();
            File file = new File(uri);
            System.out.println("file made");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

below is my folder structure:

[image: my project folder structure and class path]

can anyone pls help me in creating such executable jar using eclipse?

Thanks In Advance!!!

[image: retrying to upload image of folder structure]

Comment: Can you first ensure that file Draft_in_same_package.docx was really copied to build path in correct folder?

Comment: actually draft_in_same_package.docx prints correct sysout. but urlOfDraftInResourceFolder gives null pointer exception. Also, I have uploaded screenshot of my build path and folder structure.

Comment: What do you see, when you run: dir D:\aditya_workspace\SampleDraftMaker\bin\draftProcessing? Btw does CreateDraft.class.getResourceAsStream("Draft_in_same_package.docx") work, can you read from it?

Comment: 1. When I open dir D:\aditya_workspace\SampleDraftMaker\bin\draftProcessing , i see CreateDraft.class and Draft_in_same_package.docx these 2 files. (Im on windows) 2. for me, CreateDraft.class.getResource("Draft_in_same_package.docx"); itself works and I can read file, but as you know its not good practice to use same folder(package) for storing java code and docx files... So I want to put docx files in separate package (in resources folder) but then i cant read it from my CreateDraft.java code :(

Answer (score 0):

Following code works for me:

```
public static void testResource() throws IOException {
    InputStream stream = Deserializace.class.getResourceAsStream("resources/ser.log");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    String s;
    while ( (s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Build directory structure:

```
Test.class
resources/ser.log
```

You must ensure that your resource directory is copied to correct place.

Comment: You mean, resources should be a sub package of the package in which Test.class is present? As you can see, my CreateDraft.java is in package draftProcessing, which is child of package src. And I have made resources as a package which is sibling of src package.

Comment: You said that you do not want to mix classes with other files, so you want to store them in resources folder. Ok, then store them either in subfolder of CreateDraft (and your URL must be relative) or store them at root (and your URL msut be absolute).

Comment: yes yes. I dont want to mix classes with other files. So resources folder should be out side src. I did it as shown in screenshot attached. With folder structure as shown in screenshot (where src and resources are sibling folders, src has classes and resources has docx) what should be url for my docx file?

Comment: when you build the project, what is content of bin directory? Does it contain resources with docx file?

Comment: No. I just checked and found, in my bin dir, there is no resources folder. its one level up in dir D:\aditya_workspace\SampleDraftMaker . this D:\aditya_workspace\SampleDraftMaker has .settings, bin, resources, src these folders. and .classpath, .project these files. am i missing something in creation of resources package? how to get url of docx file in resource package with current folder structure?

Comment: sorry, I am eclipse hater, I do not know how to configure it. Once it copies resources directory correctly, it will work